# Convert contents of an attribute to function & execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take the following example:

```
<div id="Demo" data-after-load="alert('Woof!')">Loading...</div>
```

You'll note I've added a custom `data-` attribute to the `div` - what id like to do is:

- Check if div contains the attribute
- if it does, store the contents of the attribute as an anonymous function to be executed later
- Execute the anonymous function at a later point

This is what I have so far:

```
var runLater = function () {};
if ($("#Demo").attr("data-after-load")) {
    runLater = ?????;
}
runLater();
```

Comment: You may have to call it `data-afterload`. I'm not sure how well jQuery handles data attributes with hyphens in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($("#Demo").data('afterLoad') !== undefined){
    var runLater = $("#Demo").data('afterLoad');
}
eval(runLater);
```

Although, there is normally a better way than having to use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Perhaps explain what you're using this for and there might be a better design for your requirement.

Comment: oooo, Have I actually found a legitimate use for eval()? There must be 100’s of questions on SO where people are lampooned for even suggesting it? (Edit: @A.Wolff - exactly my thinking - but is there any other way?)

Comment: @HeavenCore, everything has a purpose. See my comment, but assuming you can 100% control these data attributes with **no** risk of them being manipulated, then eval is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can `eval()` the attribute...

```
var runLater = $("#Demo").attr("data-after-load");

if( runLater ) {
    eval( runLater );
}
```

...but if at all possible you should attach the function to the element with `.data()`. This way you can avoid using eval.

```
$("#Demo").data("after-load", function() {
    alert( 'Woof!' );
});

...

var runLater = $("#Demo").data("after-load");

if( runLater ) {
    runLater();
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/42NpU/)

...and if you absolutely must have the data attribute in HTML, the next best thing is to have it refer to a function, if the list of possible functions is known.

HTML:

```
<div id="Demo" data-after-load="woof">Loading...</div>
```

JS:

```
var runLater = $("#Demo").data("after-load");

var funcList = {
    woof: function() {
        alert( 'Woof!' );
    },
    foow: function() { ... }
};

if( runLater && funcList[ runLater ] ) {
    funcList[ runLater ]();
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/St45P/)